# Spring Java Mail Program running in centOS Linux Box throwing exception

Tags: java, linux, spring, centos, jakarta-mail

I wrote a java program injecting spring Mail following instructions here - [Spring EMail](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/mail.html). I wrote a JUNIT class to test it. All this is happening as part of a bigger project and that big project is developed in oracle virtual box linux centOS machine. If i run the test case in centOS i am seeing this exception. I checked some linux forums and don't see any answers quite relevant to it. I think i am not searching properly as this is my first project developing remotely in VBOX and in Linux. Can experts please help? I made sure that my SMTP host looks good.

I found some help [here - sendmail issue in centOS](http://www.zimbra.com/forums/installation/13831-solved-upgraded-5-0-oss-sendmail-problem.html)
.  -  and [here - spring forums](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?37213-why-not-work-spring-mail) - But not sure if i could follow all instructions

Stack Trace Follows.

```
2011-12-14 20:57:35,654 ERROR [main] (AbstractStep.java:212) - Encountered an error executing the step
java.lang.AssertionError
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:2120)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1912)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:248)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:389)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:306)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:296)
    at com.vzwcorp.legal.batch.core.ReportGenerator.write(ReportGenerator.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:171)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:150)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:268)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:194)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:74)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:371)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:263)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:76)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:367)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:214)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:143)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:248)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:281)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:114)
    at com.vzwcorp.legal.eplm.batch.EplmDeliveryBatchTest.testBatchJob(EplmDeliveryBatchTest.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:102)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:350)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1021)
```

Comment: What's the exception? I just see a stack strace. What does your code look like? It's hard to spot bugs or make recommendations without the code. :)

Comment: @sarnold - I ve edited the stack trace to show the exception. But the fact is that I never assert for anything in my test case. I dont understand whats this assertion error. Also to answer about my code. I have a spring batch job which runs and sends an email as a last step. this is happening in the last spring batch step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of JavaMail are you using?  What version of the JDK are you using?
Is this exception reproducible?

You're running into an assertion error in the JavaMail code that should never happen.
It's asserting that it holds the lock on the current object.  Since the method making
the assertion is only ever called from synchronized methods, and in particular the
Service.connect method is synchronized, this should never happen.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your firewall settings maybe your centOS virtual machine is not allowing access to the email server?

Also is the email server on the same machine as the centOS or a remote?

Comment: I'll check answer for both the questions and get back.

Answer (score 1):

I encounterd the same error. My configuration was (cut-outs from the pom.xml)

```
<spring-version>3.1.2.RELEASE</spring-version>
```

and Java Mail

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

After I upgraded to Java Mail 1.4.5 the problem disappeared.